# Why does inline not work here?

Tags: c++, constructor

Edit: Big Aplogies - I have had gTime declared after gUniverse but posted it here wrong after being asked to provide more code. I confused it with an earlier version of my program where actually it was opposite around.

I have a class gUniverse that contains a declaration of a a pointer to an instance of another object of the class gTime;

```
class gUniverse;
class gTime;

class gUniverse
    {
    public:
    gUniverse():UniverseTime(new gTime(1) ){}
    ~gUniverse();

    gTime* UniverseTime;
    };

class gTime
    {
  public:
    gTime();
    gTime(int start);
    void StartTimer();
    double ElapsedTime();

  private:
    clock_t StartTime;
    clock_t StopTime;
};
```

This does not compile with "incomplete type".

However, when I make an outside declaration, that is:

```
class gUniverse
    {
    public:
    gUniverse();
    ~gUniverse();

    gTime* UniverseTime;
    };

gUniverse::gUniverse():UniverseTime(new gTime(1) )
   {
   }
```

Then this is all cool now. I want to understand what's the problem and if the second case is okay to do, given that I take care of all destructors and copy constructors.

Comment: Is latest example happens within the same file or in separate .h and .cpp?

Comment: In the same.... Is it better to slpit into a .h?

Comment: Just the same way you typed it? (surely you've missing ';' so it's not 1:1 code). Without anything in between? And #include statements are same for both examples?

Comment: You can't instantiate an incomplete type, which is exactly what you're doing in the inline constructor. You're forward declaring `gTime`, which means its type is not available. You're even passing an argument to the constructor of `gTime`, when in fact your forward-declare is already all-but-admitting you don't even know what it *is* yet. It works in the .cpp file because somewhere above you're actually pulling the definition of `gTime` (the *real* one) in the translation unit. And you need semi-colons on your class-closures. Can you show where `gTime` is declared ?

Comment: If the definition of `gTime` is available, they should both work. [See it live](http://ideone.com/1FzHsU).

Comment: And though I still think it related, I just realized glancing at the post the `class gTime;` all by its lonesome is actually part of your intro-paragraph, not part of the code. I still think the compiler is right, you have an incomplete type, but talk about stars-aligning.

Comment: @user2856452 there is no C++11-restricted code in this snippet. You're update is pretty telling. You say your forward-declare your classes at the top. Is the formal definition of `class gTime` *after* the formal definition of `class gUniverse`? (note: note the forwards, the *actual* definition). I'm betting so, and if so, see my prior long-winded comment.

Comment: Ok, what's the best way to deal with it? Shall I create a .h file or can I leave my second case that compiles fine and leave it to be?

Comment: Meaning of a code fragment is determined by context, which includes all of the preceding compilation unit. We don't see the context. Show your **entire** files, otherwise it's all empty talk.

Comment: I cannot show you 8500 lines of code.. the snippet is the essence of the problem.

Comment: It's not the essence of the problem because the code above is correct. The code you have is wrong, but you've fixed that error in posting your code here. Perhaps that will give you a clue?

Comment: So make a short example which reproduces the problem, **and post the entire example**.

Comment: I have not fixed it. It does not compile.

Comment: [See it live](http://ideone.com/1FzHsU). Minus the cruft and providing implementation where needed, this works. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I took your code, added the <ctime> header (needed for clock_t). It compiles.

Comment: The one answer beneath solved the problem. I understand now. I don't have anything useful in the ".h" file and that's the issue...

Comment: @user2856452 The answer below is incorrect. (or rather the advice given is irrelevant). If that and that alone makes a difference then you are using a broken C++ compiler. Far more likely I think is that you've just confused yourself.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @user2856452 there is no way that answer solved the problem if your compiler is remotely standard-compliant. If it did, then I want to know what your target platform and toolchain is.

Comment: First compilers fine under g++ 4.8.1 on cygwin.

Comment: @user2856452 'I understand it now', expect you don't, your understanding has actually decreased, even the person whose answer you accepted has now said that it isn't a correct answer at all.

Comment: @user2856452 I see you've edited the code and reversed the order in which you declared the classes. Very sneaky but it at least shows you understand the problem now.

Comment: As I suspected o-many-comments ago. Ok, sanity back in check, moving on.

Comment: I just deleted an answer I submitted that had been accepted.  There was some debate as to whether it was relevant, and I had some doubts myself.  The order of declarations of members and methods within a class doesn't/shouldn't matter, in a simple example like this.  Apologies to the questioner for deleting the answer he/she accepted!

Comment: My question still applies. Why does it not work inline but works outline? Is there a way to have it inline?

Comment: It works inline if you have the gTime class before the gUniverse class. The issue is that when the compiler sees `gUniverse():UniverseTime(new gTime(1) ){}` it must have seen the full `gtime` definition.

Comment: Other than that I MUST have it outline? Can you post this as quick answer?

Comment: Answering your just-asked question, because the out-of-line constructor you have is *after* the formal definition of `gTime`. i.e., your real code likely has (1) forward decls, (2) gUniverse formal definition, (3) gTime formal definition, (4) gUniverse constructor. etc... Inline, the type of gTime is still incomplete, By doing what I just described you delay the need to "know" that formal type until after it has actually been defined.

Comment: Yes other than that it must be outline.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know and thought that both were always equivalent until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the important expression:

```
new gTime(1)
```

This line of code cannot be compiled unless the compiler knows the interface to the `gTime` class.  For example, it needs to see if it has a constructor that can accept an `int` or some other constructor that can take `1` as a single argument.

One solution is to move the entire `gTime` class nearer to the start of the file, above the `gUniverse` class.

Alternatively, you can move this `new ...` to later in the file, below `gTime`.  You did this by moving that definition outside the class and into:

```
gUniverse::gUniverse():UniverseTime(new gTime(1) )    {   }
```

However this works only if you place it after the `gTime` class.  If you had simply placed this after the `gUniverse` class and before the `gTime` class, then this wouldn't work.  So this isn't really about inline versus external - the important thing is that this definition of the `gUniverse` constructor must be after the `gTime` class.

Comment: ohh yes, that makes perfectly sense. Does having a .h file can help with these issues too? I have declared all my classes at the beginning of the cpp file instead.